# spring jersey jackson - StdDeserializer class not found exception

Tags: spring, jersey, jackson

I am trying to make my spring-hibernate project also available for my jersey rest service.
However, even I am not sure it woths mentioning that I think the dependency management I made using maven occures the following exception. The wierd thing in this case is I get this exception only for the first request to my rest service. The second and further requests just responses as I expected.

The last thing, I added jackson in addition to jersey because of taking advantages of jackson in order to keep consistency (when response includes list, and list has 1 element, with only jersey it causes some incosistency, but with jackson it is ok)

If you need me to share my pom please let me know. Thanks.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2836)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1160)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1668)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospector(MapperConfigurator.java:173)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._resolveIntrospectors(MapperConfigurator.java:146)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator._setAnnotations(MapperConfigurator.java:133)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.MapperConfigurator.getDefaultMapper(MapperConfigurator.java:70)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.locateMapper(JacksonJsonProvider.java:648)
at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.writeTo(JacksonJsonProvider.java:500)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.writeTo(JacksonProviderProxy.java:160)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: HI, we are also facing the same error. We jsut chnaged jackson jars version in pom.xml from 1.8.5 to 1.9.2.. magic.. Its working.. we suspect there is some issue with 1.8.5 version.. But its working fine as soon as we chnage to 1.9.2 version.

Comment: Hım thanks for your idea, it is worth trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the following class into my spring project in order to get over this problem.

```
@Provider
@Component
public class JSONProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider 
{
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public JSONProvider() {
    /** without setting this, StdDeserializer not found exception occurs */
    AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();
    AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
    AnnotationIntrospector pair = new AnnotationIntrospector.Pair(primary, secondary);
    mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
    mapper.configure(Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    setMapper(mapper);
}
```

}